# How to transfer data between adapters?

Tags: android, android-adapter, transfer

I have these two adapters OperateClassroomAdapter and EditClassRoom adapter

```
public class OperateClassroomsAdapter extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<OperateClassroomsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Classroom> classroomList;

private AdapterClickListener adapterClickListener;

public OperateClassroomsAdapter(ArrayList<Classroom> classroomList) {
    this.classroomList = classroomList;
}

/**
 * Set on item click listener
 * @param adapterClickListener AdapterClickListener
 */
public void setAdapterClickListener(AdapterClickListener adapterClickListener) {
    this.adapterClickListener = adapterClickListener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.operate_classroom_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Classroom item = classroomList.get(position);
    viewHolder.text.setText(item.getName());
    viewHolder.counter.setText(String.valueOf(item.getStudentNumber()));
    Log.d("sn",String.valueOf(item.getStudentNumber()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return classroomList == null ? 0 : classroomList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView text;
    TextView counter;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        counter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (adapterClickListener != null) {
            adapterClickListener.OnItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
   }
```

Here in onBindViewHolder Log.d("sn") it shows proper values whereas in the code below

```
public class EditClassroomsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EditClassroomsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Classroom> classroomList;
    private ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;

    private PopupClickListener popupClickListener;
    private AdapterClickListener adapterClickListener;
    private DeleteClassBtnClickListener deleteClassBtnClickListener;
    private EditClassBtnClickListener editClassBtnClickListener;

    private Random mRandom = new Random();
    String colorarray[]= new String[]{
            "#ffff66",
            "#99ff66",
            "#ffffff",
            "#b3ffff",
            "#ff8080",
            "#ccdcff",
            "#c3c3c3"
    };
    public EditClassroomsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Classroom> classroomList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.classroomList = classroomList;
        listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(context);
    }

    /**
     * Set on item click listener
     * @param adapterClickListener AdapterClickListener
     */
    public void setAdapterClickListener(AdapterClickListener adapterClickListener) {
        this.adapterClickListener = adapterClickListener;
    }

    /**
     * Set on pop-up men item click listener
     * @param popupClickListener PopupClickListener
     */
    public void setPopupClickListener(PopupClickListener popupClickListener) {
        this.popupClickListener = popupClickListener;
    }

    public void setDeleteClassBtnClickListener(DeleteClassBtnClickListener deleteClassBtnClickListener){
        this.deleteClassBtnClickListener=deleteClassBtnClickListener;
    }

    public void setEditClassBtnClickListener(EditClassBtnClickListener editClassBtnClickListener) {
        this.editClassBtnClickListener = editClassBtnClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.edit_classroom_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Classroom item = classroomList.get(position);
        Log.d("sn22",String.valueOf(item.getStudentNumber()));

        viewHolder.text.setText(item.getName());
        viewHolder.student_count.setText(String.valueOf(item.getStudentNumber()));
        viewHolder.settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listPopupWindow != null) {
                    setListPopUpWindow(v, position);
                }
            }
        });
        /*
        New Delete button added
        */
        viewHolder.del_class.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(deleteClassBtnClickListener!=null)
                    deleteClassBtnClickListener.OnDeleteclassBtnClicked(position);
            }
        });
        /*
            edit_class button added
        */
        viewHolder.edit_class.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(editClassBtnClickListener!=null)
                    editClassBtnClickListener.OnEditclassBtnClicked(position);
            }
        });
        Random rand=new Random();
        int rgen=rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        viewHolder.thumbnail.getLayoutParams().height = getRandomIntInRange(350,200);
        viewHolder.thumbnail.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorarray[rgen]));
        Glide.with(context).load(item.getThumbnail()).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        //   Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);
    }

    protected int getRandomIntInRange(int max, int min){
        return mRandom.nextInt((max-min)+min)+min;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return classroomList == null ? 0 : classroomList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView text;
        ImageButton settings;
        ImageView thumbnail;
        ImageButton del_class,edit_class;
        TextView student_count;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            thumbnail=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_image) ;
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            student_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_count);
            settings = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.settings);
            del_class=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.del_class);
            edit_class=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (adapterClickListener != null) {
                adapterClickListener.OnItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * List pop up menu window
     * @param anchor View
     * @param classroomPosition List item's position
     */
    private void setListPopUpWindow(View anchor, final int classroomPosition) {
        listPopupWindow.dismiss();

        listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.edit_classroom)));
        listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(anchor);
        listPopupWindow.setContentWidth(context.getResources()
                .getInteger(R.integer.list_pop_up_width));
        listPopupWindow.setDropDownGravity(Gravity.END);
        listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
        listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int menuItemPosition, long id) {
                if (popupClickListener != null) {
                    popupClickListener.OnPopupClick(classroomPosition, menuItemPosition);
                }

                listPopupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
        listPopupWindow.show();
    }

}
```

The Log.d("sn22") is showing values as 0.Why is this happening ?Or how do i get values from OperateClassroomAdapter here ?

My main point is im passing same arraylist ,still sn22 shows 0 and other shows proper values.Also these are 2 different fragment.
Here is the code for their respective classes where theyre used.

```
public class EditClassroomFragment extends Fragment {

private Context context;
private  static int p=0;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private RecyclerView list;
private ArrayList<Classroom> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private EditClassroomsAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager2 = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
private TextView emptyText; //empty list view text

public EditClassroomFragment() {}

public static EditClassroomFragment newInstance() {
    EditClassroomFragment editClassroomFragment = new EditClassroomFragment();
    return editClassroomFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.refreshable_list, container, false);

    context = rootView.getContext();
    list = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new EditClassroomsAdapter(context, arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager2);
    list.setHasFixedSize(true);

    emptyText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.emptyText);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new SelectClassrooms().execute();
        }
    });
    addDeleteClassBtnClickListener();
    addAdapterClickListener();
    addPopupClickListener();
    addEditClassBtnClickListener();

    new SelectClassrooms().execute();


    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Set empty list text
 */
private void setEmptyText() {
    if (emptyText != null) {
        if (arrayList.isEmpty()) {
            emptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            emptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the given classroom name already exists
 * @param classroomName Selected classroom
 * @return
 */
private boolean isAlreadyExist(String classroomName) {
    boolean isAlreadyExist = false;

    for (Classroom classroom : arrayList) {
        if (classroom.getName().equals(classroomName)) {
            isAlreadyExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isAlreadyExist;
}

/**
 * Add new class item
 */
public void addClassroom() {
    final PromptDialog promptDialog = new PromptDialog(context);
    promptDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok));
    promptDialog.setAllCaps();
    promptDialog.setAlphanumeric();
    promptDialog.setOnPositiveClickListener(new PromptListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnPrompt(String promptText) {
            closeKeyboard();

            promptDialog.dismiss();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(promptText)) {
                if (!isAlreadyExist(promptText)) {
                    new InsertClassroom().execute(promptText);
                } else {
                    //alert
                    CustomAlertDialog customAlertDialog = new CustomAlertDialog(context);
                    customAlertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.couldNotInsertClassroom));
                    customAlertDialog.setPositiveButtonText(getString(R.string.ok));
                    customAlertDialog.showDialog();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    promptDialog.show();
}

public void addClassroom2(String st) {
    if(st.equals(null)==false) {
        if (!isAlreadyExist(st)) {
            new InsertClassroom().execute(st);
        } else {
            //alert
            CustomAlertDialog customAlertDialog = new CustomAlertDialog(context);
            customAlertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.couldNotInsertClassroom));
            customAlertDialog.setPositiveButtonText(getString(R.string.ok));
            customAlertDialog.showDialog();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Change the selected class name
 * @param classroomId current classroom to be changed
 * @param content current name of the classroom
 */
public void editClassroom(final int classroomId, String content) {
    final PromptDialog promptDialog = new PromptDialog(context);
    promptDialog.setContent(content);
    promptDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok));
    promptDialog.setAllCaps();
    promptDialog.setAlphanumeric();
    promptDialog.setOnPositiveClickListener(new PromptListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnPrompt(String promptText) {
            closeKeyboard();

            promptDialog.dismiss();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(promptText)) {
                new UpdateClassroom().execute(String.valueOf(classroomId), promptText);
            }
        }
    });
    promptDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Delete classroom
 * @param classroom Selected classroom
 */
private void deleteClassroom(final Classroom classroom) {
    //show alert before deleting
    CustomAlertDialog customAlertDialog = new CustomAlertDialog(context);
    customAlertDialog.setMessage(classroom.getName()
            + getString(R.string.sureToDelete));
    customAlertDialog.setPositiveButtonText(getString(R.string.delete));
    customAlertDialog.setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.cancel));
    customAlertDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnAlertClick() {
        @Override
        public void OnPositive() {
            new DeleteClassroom().execute(classroom.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void OnNegative() {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
    customAlertDialog.showDialog();
}

/**
 * Go inside classroom to add, change or delete students
 * @param classroom
 */
private void showStudents(Classroom classroom) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditStudentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("classroom", classroom);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.move_in_from_bottom,
            R.anim.stand_still);
}

/**
 * List item click event
 */
private void addAdapterClickListener() {
    adapter.setAdapterClickListener(new AdapterClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClick(int position) {
            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > position) {
                showStudents(arrayList.get(position));
                Log.d("sn44",String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getStudentNumber()));
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Pop-up menu item click event
 */
public void addPopupClickListener() {
    adapter.setPopupClickListener(new PopupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnPopupClick(int itemPosition, int menuPosition) {
            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > itemPosition) {
                Classroom classroom = arrayList.get(itemPosition);

                if (menuPosition == ClassroomPopup.CHANGE_NAME.getValue()) {
                    editClassroom(classroom.getId(), classroom.getName());
                } else if (menuPosition == ClassroomPopup.DELETE_CLASSROOM.getValue()) {
                    deleteClassroom(classroom);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

/*
    Edit button and delete button listeners
 */

public void addDeleteClassBtnClickListener()
{
    adapter.setDeleteClassBtnClickListener(new DeleteClassBtnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnDeleteclassBtnClicked(int position) {
            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > position) {
                Classroom classroom = arrayList.get(position);
                deleteClassroom(classroom);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void addEditClassBtnClickListener()
{
    adapter.setEditClassBtnClickListener(new EditClassBtnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnEditclassBtnClicked(int position) {
            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > position) {
                Classroom classroom = arrayList.get(position);
                editClassroom(classroom.getId(), classroom.getName());
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Select classrooms from DB
 */
private class SelectClassrooms extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Classroom>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Classroom> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(context);
        ArrayList<Classroom> tmpList = databaseManager.selectClassrooms();

        return tmpList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Classroom> tmpList) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        arrayList.clear();

        if (tmpList != null) {
            arrayList.addAll(tmpList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            setEmptyText();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Insert classroom name into DB
 */
private class InsertClassroom extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String classroom = params[0];
        DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(context);
        boolean isSuccessful = databaseManager.insertClassroom(classroom);

        return isSuccessful;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isSuccessful) {
        if (isSuccessful) {
            new SelectClassrooms().execute();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Update classroom name in the DB
 */
private class UpdateClassroom extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String classroomId = params[0];
        String newName = params[1];
        DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(context);
        boolean isSuccessful = databaseManager.updateClassroomName(classroomId, newName);

        return isSuccessful;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isSuccessful) {
        if (isSuccessful) {
            new SelectClassrooms().execute();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Delete a classroom item from DB
 */
private class DeleteClassroom extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        int classroomId = params[0];
        DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(context);
        boolean isSuccessful = databaseManager.deleteClassroom(classroomId);

        return isSuccessful;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isSuccessful) {
        if (isSuccessful) {
            new SelectClassrooms().execute();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Closes keyboard for disabling interruption
 */
private void closeKeyboard(){
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
}
```

---

```
public class AttendancesFragment extends Fragment {

private Context context;

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private RecyclerView list;
private ArrayList<Classroom> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private OperateClassroomsAdapter adapter;

private TextView emptyText; //empty list view text


public AttendancesFragment() {}

public static AttendancesFragment newInstance() {
    AttendancesFragment attendancesFragment = new AttendancesFragment();
    return attendancesFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.refreshable_list, container, false);

    context = rootView.getContext();

    list = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new OperateClassroomsAdapter(arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    list.setHasFixedSize(true);

    emptyText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.emptyText);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new SelectClassrooms().execute();
        }
    });

    addAdapterClickListener();

    new SelectClassrooms().execute();


    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Set empty list text
 */
private void setEmptyText() {
    if (emptyText != null) {
        if (arrayList.isEmpty()) {
            emptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            emptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * List item click event
 */
public void addAdapterClickListener() {
    adapter.setAdapterClickListener(new AdapterClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClick(int position) {
            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, TakeAttendanceActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("classroom", arrayList.get(position));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.move_in_from_bottom,
                        R.anim.stand_still);
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Select classrooms from DB
 */
private class SelectClassrooms extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Classroom>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Classroom> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(context);
        ArrayList<Classroom> tmpList = databaseManager.selectClassroomsWithStudentNumber();

        return tmpList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Classroom> tmpList) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        arrayList.clear();

        if (tmpList != null) {
            arrayList.addAll(tmpList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            setEmptyText();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Snackbar.make(list, getString(R.string.saved), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do you pass same ArryList for both adapter or make changes at any time?

Comment: @user2351509 Mention all the details of your requirement while asking the question. Are you calling both the adapter in same activity or fragment?

Comment: Post your activity code. From where you construct classroom list?

Comment: I edited it as per your request. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is how pass from data from adapter to another, you can use `SharedPreferences` to save and get data from adapter to another.

Hope this help you

Comment: As no one is replying forward, I need to use our method.Can you tell how to write to Sharedprefrences in my OperateClassroomAdapter and read that Sharedprefrences in EditClassroomAdapter.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example there is a useful example.  If you don't understand, I'll try to explain you with much detail ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,you saved me :) ,but i think there might be a proper solution this is not a proper one.